# Microsoft Teams outgoing webhooks broken?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am developing an integration in Teams using outgoing webhooks and it was working fine until recently, but now, my webhook keeps replying there is an error with my request (Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request)

I had this problem at first, but I solved it by having my service send the correct reply following the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook)

Something like :

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "text": "This is a reply!"
}
```

But now, I always get an error response, even though my service is replying with the supposedly correct json.

It looks like something changed in the implementation, but the documentation is not up to date

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you generating a response? I just checked [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-outgoing-webhook-nodejs) and it works like a charm. The message it sends is exactly the same as in your example.

Comment: yea, turns out my service was only accepting GET and Teams is issuing a POST.